# Dynamically assign URL hyperlinks to an image in XSLT, to be placed in InDesign CS5

Tags: xslt, hyperlink, adobe-indesign

I am currently using the following XSLT code to successfully/dynamically place a facebook, linkedin and twitter icon, using a conditional, if the member data in XLM shows that they have facebook (ie if the facebook element is non-empty). How do I get the XSLT to InDesign CS5 output (not outputting to html) to automatically assign the corresponding/unique facebook URL to the image? Thanks

Here is the XSLT code (which i got to give the icon images for facebook, twitter and linked in, if there is a URL in existence):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
<!ENTITY mdash  "&#8212;">]>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<memberdata>  
<xsl:for-each select="memberdata/memberinfo">
<xsl:sort select="SortKey"/>

<memberdata>


<xsl:if test="twitter[.!='']">
<twitter><xsl:attribute name="href">file://logos/twitter.jpg</xsl:attribute></twitter>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="facebook[.!='']">
<facebook><xsl:attribute name="href">file://logos/facebook.jpg</xsl:attribute></facebook>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="linkedin[.!='']">
<linkedin><xsl:attribute name="href">file://logos/linkedin.jpg</xsl:attribute></linkedin>
</xsl:if>


</memberdata>

</xsl:for-each>

</memberdata> 

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="twitter">
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="facebook">
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="linkedin">
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the XLM:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<memberdata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
<memberinfo>

<email>email1@abc.com</email>
<facebook>http://www.URL1a.com</facebook>
<linkedin>http://www.URL1b.com</linkedin>
<vimeo>http://www.URL1c.com</vimeo>

</memberinfo>
<memberinfo>

<email>email2@abc.com</email>
<facebook>http://www.URL2a.com</facebook>
<linkedin>http://www.URL2b.com</linkedin>
<vimeo>http://www.URL2c.com</vimeo>

</memberinfo>
</memberdata>
```

Comment: please note that while the facebook image is the same, each member data may contain different/unique URLs in the XLM facebook element, ie www.facebook.com/abc, www.facebook.com/xyz, etc.  So the goal is to have the facebook icon appear (which is already working ok), but also have it appear with the corresponding URL is www.facebook.com/abc etc assigned to it, so that when we export to PDF it's a live link. Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide a complete (but as minimal as possible) XML document and the complete (as minimal as possible and still relevant) result you want to be produced. Withouth these you do not have a proble m definition.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, just added the XML document as well as a more complete XSL. Thx still learning as you can tell. If you are going to provide code which requires any other edits to any other part of the XSL (like top part etc) can you please outline those as well? Thanks!

Comment: Tom, could you add an example of the result you are trying to generate? I'm not familiar with "InDesign CS5 output" but if you can show what it is I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `if` for your elements - this will handle the template for you:

```
<xsl:template match="twitter[.!='']">
    <twitter>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">file://logos/twitter.jpg</xsl:attribute>
    </twitter>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="facebook[.!='']">
    <facebook>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">file://logos/facebook.jpg</xsl:attribute>
    </facebook>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="linkedin[.!='']">
    <linkedin>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">file://logos/linkedin.jpg</xsl:attribute>
    </linkedin>
</xsl:template>
```

Maybe you can add the desired output for your sample xml ... it's not clear what should happen with `<email />` elements for example.